# Select all customers but not from current month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i get all customers, but not records that have signed up in CURRENT month? I thought this would work, but nope - what to do?

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE deleted = 0 AND (MONTH(created) != MONTH(NOW() AND YEAR(created) != YEAR(NOW())))
```

Comment: Between '2016-05-01' and CURDATE()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
   WHERE (deleted = 0) AND  not (
         (MONTH(created) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
         (YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW()))
```

Comment: Note that this solution cannot use an index

Answer (score 2):

As a basic rule you should avoid calculatons on columns, they result in more CPU usage and can't use indexes.

A Standard SQL compliant solution (which also works in MySQL) simply finds the last day of the previous month:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE deleted = 0
  AND created <= CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MONTH(NOW()` should have a closing bracket i.e :- `MONTH(NOW())`

`MONTH(created) != MONTH(NOW())` will filter out the customers whose created date's month is not equal to current month
and `YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW())` will filter out the current Year

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE deleted = 0 
and MONTH(created) != MONTH(NOW()) 
and YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Comment: comment and explanation added, hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM customers  WHERE deleted = 0 AND  not (
             (MONTH(created) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
             (YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW()))
```

**OR**

```
 SELECT * FROM customers  WHERE deleted = 0 AND  !(
             (MONTH(created) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
             (YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW()))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change `AND` to `OR`:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    customers 
where 
    deleted = 0 
    and 
    (
        year(created) != year(now()) or month(created) != month(now())

    );
```